# Jason's Deli has two different kinds of soft serve, what's the difference?

Tags: ice-cream

[Jason's Deli](http://www.jasonsdeli.com/) clearly has two kinds of Free Ice Cream,

1. The Good Kind.
2. The Bad Kind.

The Good Kind is the same kind of soft serve you'll find at McDonalds, and Burger King. I'm wondering what's the difference between though between The Good Kind, and The Bad Kind.

The Bad Kind is at the Shepherd Store, and the Humble Store.

The Good Kind is at the Kingwood Store.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Jason's Deli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to Jason's Deli and here was their response,

> My name is Alice Jones and I am a part of the leadership team at the Shephred Square location. First and foremost I would like to thank you for providing feedback in regards to the ice cream. Let me be the first to apologize for the inconsistency provided at the different delis. To be completely honest the reasons for the difference is the machines which the ice cream is process. The ice cream machine at the Kingwood location is an **Electrofreeze** verse the **Taylor Machine** at the Shepherd Square location.
>
> The Electrofreeze machine is a more updated version of the Taylor which has more airflow allowing a fluffier product. I would like to re ensure you that all deli use the same product unfortunately because of the process within the machines are different which may result in a different taste. If you have any additional question and or concerns please feel free to reach out. Lastly, I attempted to reach out via telephone however unsuccessful therefore resulting in this email.

So they claim the difference is in the airflow of the two brands.